# git apply --check file.patch ingores first `/`

Tags: git, path, diff

I'm trying to apply a self-created patch to a project.
So I did the following command:

```
diff -ru src /mnt/windows/Programming/pull_requests/himalaya/src > file.patch
```

Now these are the first lines in the `file.patch`:

```
diff --color -ru src/config/tui/tui.rs /mnt/windows/Programming/pull_requests/himalaya/src/config/tui/tui.rs
--- src/config/tui/tui.rs   2021-06-07 20:50:19.398724000 +0200
+++ /mnt/windows/Programming/pull_requests/himalaya/src/config/tui/tui.rs   2021-07-07 10:06:40.787428476 +0200
```

Now if I do `git apply --check file.patch`, than I'm getting this:

```
error: mnt/windows/Programming/pull_requests/himalaya/src/config/tui/tui.rs: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the first `/` is missing for `/mnt`. Why though? Why isn't it correct? The patch looks fine for me.

## Hint

I'm on linux, `windows` is just a directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want git to check something that describes moving your repo's file to a path outside your repo, try the [`--unsafe-paths` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---unsafe-paths), and also add `-p 0` to keep the leading slash.

IMHO : if your intention is only to check if the patch can be applied correctly to your local `src/config/tui/tui.rs` file, you would be better off editing the patch manually, to drop the absolute prefix from the 3rd line :

```
+++ src/config/tui/tui.rs   2021-07-07 10:06:40.787428476 +0200
```

---

The doc for `--unsafe-paths` option give an indication of why your patch is rejected :

> **--unsafe-paths**
>
> By default, a patch that affects outside the working area (either a Git controlled working tree, or the current working directory when "git apply" is used as a replacement of GNU patch) is rejected as a mistake (or a mischief).
>
> When `git apply` is used as a "better GNU patch", the user can pass the `--unsafe-paths` option to override this safety check. This option has no effect when `--index` or `--cached` is in use.

Comment: Executing `git apply --check --unsafe-paths file.patch` returns the same error message.

Comment: ok, my bad. What is your expectation regarding this patch, and this `git apply --check`, though ?

Comment: Yesterday, I coded on my laptop but then I saw that its state wasn't up to date, so I thought that it doesn't matter since I could create a patch of it and apply it on the original repository. Anyway, I just copied the files from my Laptop to the repository and rewrote everything again, which was originally there in the repository. But thank you for your help! Should we still try to find a solution on my question?

Comment: Note that `git apply` defaults to `-p1`, which strips off a single leading component, e.g., `a/` and `b/`. It sure looks like the "leading component" in `/mnt/foo` is `/`, leaving `mnt/foo`. Adding `-p0` will make `git apply` strip off no leading components, though you'll probably still need `--unsafe-paths` (which I wasn't even aware of: if I have patches of dubious paths I always path-sanitize them first!).

Comment: @TornaxO7 : there are many ways to do that (copy over files from another source on disk), that do not involve applying patches with shady paths. Since it looks like you resolved your issue on your own, I think we can leave this question as is.

Comment: @torek what do you mean with `I always path-sanitize them first`?

Comment: @TornaxO7: I mean I look over the diff, find each `^diff ` line to see which files are affected, and if some of the paths look hinky to me, *edit* the patch so that the paths are good (or don't apply the patch if it is clearly full of malware, etc).

Comment: Ok, so adding `-p0` seems to work (at least in my test). Although I couldn't apply the patch, you answered my question. Thank you guys!